# Create multiple ranger polices with one json file

Tags: apache-ranger

Currently using rest api with curl operation for create/update/delete ranger policies from single policy.json file. I want make it more dynamically in which we can able to create/update/delete multiple policies with same policy.json file.

Command:

```
curl -ik -u ${RANGER_USERNAME}:${RANGER_PASSWORD} -d @policy.json -H Content-type:application/json -X POST ${HOSTNAME}/service/public/api/policy
```

Is there any way to achieve it, please let me know.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance